# Link against different glibc

Tags: linker, g++, glibc

I installed glibc-2.18 into my home directory and want to link an application against it:

```
$ g++ -pthread -o tsx_test tsx_test.cpp -Wl,--rpath=/home/hl/lib/ \
  -Wl,--dynamic-linker=/home/hl/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Compiling and linking works fine using g++4.7.3, however, fails when executing it:

```
$ ./tsx_test
./tsx_test: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 definitely exists, when I compile without "--rpath" the same libstdc++.so.6 is linked and everything works fine.

```
$ ldd tsx_test
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff42bd4000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f42aa3aa000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f42aa194000)
libpthread.so.0 => /home/hl/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f42a9f75000)
libc.so.6 => /home/hl/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f42a9bc8000)
libm.so.6 => /home/hl/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f42a98c5000)
/home/hl/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f42aa6c9000)
```

Comment: I copied /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 into /home/hl/lib and it worked. Is it a permission problem, can't I mix root owned and user owned libs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 definitely exists

... but your libc doesn't look there.

You can set your RPATH like so: `-Wl,-rpath=/home/hl/lib:/usr/lib`, or you can edit `/home/hl/etc/ld.so.conf` and tell your libc to look in `/usr/lib` (*after* `/home/hl/lib`).j

> Is it a permission problem, can't I mix root owned and user owned libs?

No. You can *definitely* mix and match root-owned and user-owned libraries.